# How to conditionally use return inside an observable in angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I have an angular 13 HTTP call and am subscribing to an observable. How can I conditionally call a return statement based on the length of the object passed as a payload to the HTTP call.

Sample code of what I want to achieve:

```
public myApiCall(userId: string,customId: string, payload: {}): Observable<any> {
  if(payload.length > 0 ){
    return this.httpClient.post<any>(environment.apiUrlBasePath + environment.USER_DETAILS, payload);
 } else {
   return this.httpClient.post<any>(environment.apiUrlBasePath + environment.NO_USER_DETAILS,payload); 
 }          
}
```

How can I use a conditional statement inside an angular http call.

Comment: What is the payload type, doing {}.length wont work

Comment: @ukn payload is an object, so basically I will check the length of the object, if the object is empty or no.

Comment: the object doesnt have a length unless its an array. So are you only looking to validate if the object is not empty or the object can be an array

Comment: @ukn the object length is not an issue, assume its an array for now, I can manage that. I just gave that as a possible sample. What I really need to fix is the conditional return statements.
So have the first return called when some condition is true, else call the second return.

Comment: If you dont have a problem with the if statement then your return looks fine and it should be working

Comment: ohh... my bad... wonder why it was not working?? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

`payload` is defined as an object `{}` instead of an array. `length` is not a property of a object.

You can check if the object is `undefined`, you can also test if the object is empty by getting it properties as an array like this: `Object.keys(payload).length === 0`

Answer (score 0):

For a more *Reactive Approach* You can use the RxJs Conditional Operator *iff* to achieve that.

The iff operator takes 3 arguments, first when being your condition, 2nd and 3rd being your different services that return an Observable.

If the condition is **true** subscribe to the first observable *(HTTP call)*, if it is **false** subscribe to the second observable

```js
 iif(
      () => {
           //Add your condition here
           return payload.length > 0;
         },
       this.httpClient.post<any>(environment.apiUrlBasePath + environment.USER_DETAILS, payload),
       this.httpClient.post<any>(environment.apiUrlBasePath + environment.NO_USER_DETAILS,payload)
     )
     .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
     .subscribe((items)=> {
         this.someData = items;
     });
```